# Pairs of duplicate, identical rows. Update just one of them

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, row-number

Working on pretty large table in SQL-Server. Table has some identical rows. I need to remove duplicate rows. Problem is I cannot alter this table i.e. to create an ID column.

I could update one column value of the other row on pairs of duplicates. Then delete afterwards using this value.

How to update only one these rows? 
For example: Firstly / lastly inserted, First occurrence, newest / oldest..

Thanks!

table Structure

```
NrValue |   Comment |   Value1  |   Value2  |   Value3      |
--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|---------------|
00000   |   data0   |   zz      |   top     |   vivalasvegas|
00100   |   NULL    |   N/A     |   sex     |   no          |
00100   |   NULL    |   N/A     |   sex     |   no          |
00200   |   NULL    |   female  |   sex     |   yes         |
00200   |   NULL    |   female  |   sex     |   yes         |
00300   |   NULL    |   male    |   sex     |   yesplease   |
00300   |   NULL    |   male    |   sex     |   yesplease   |
00400   |   data21  |   M       |   --      |   na          |
00500   |   NULL    |   F       |   ezig    |   na          |
```

So, I could use 'Comment' -column to update but I cannot touch other than duplicate rows. I know by `NrValue` which rows can be updated. 
Result would be:

```
NrValue |   Comment |   Value1  |   Value2  |   Value3      |
--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|---------------|
00000   |   data0   |   zz      |   top     |   vivalasvegas|
00100   |   1       |   N/A     |   sex     |   no          |
00100   |   2       |   N/A     |   sex     |   no          |
00200   |   3       |   female  |   sex     |   yes         |
00200   |   4       |   female  |   sex     |   yes         |
00300   |   5       |   male    |   sex     |   yesplease   |
00300   |   6       |   male    |   sex     |   yesplease   |
00400   |   data21  |   M       |   --      |   na          |
00500   |   NULL    |   F       |   ezig    |   na          |
```

Lastly I delete rows where `NrValue` = 00100, 00200 or 00300 AND `Comment` = 2, 4 or 6.

Comment: You could use a CTE to number and delete the records in one go.  Without data and table structure, I don't think an exact answer can be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AllRelevantColumns ORDER BY SomeOrderCriteria)
```

This will generate a `1` for all rows, but duplicates get a `2` (or a `3` ...)

You might place this value in a new column or use this for cleaning...

### UPDATE Following your test data...

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(NrValue INT,Comment VARCHAR(100),Value1 VARCHAR(100),Value2 VARCHAR(100),Value3 VARCHAR(100));      
INSERT INTO @mockup  VALUES
 (00000,'data0','zz','top','vivalasvegas')
,(00100,'NULL','N/A','sex','no')
,(00100,'NULL','N/A','sex','no')
,(00200,'NULL','female','sex','yes')
,(00200,'NULL','female','sex','yes')
,(00300,'NULL','male','sex','yesplease')
,(00300,'NULL','male','sex','yesplease')
,(00400,'data21','M','--','na')
,(00500,'NULL','F','ezig','na');

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NrValue ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS DupNr
          ,*
    FROM @mockup 
)
DELETE FROM Numbered 
WHERE DupNr>1;

SELECT * FROM @mockup;
```

This concept is called *updateable CTE*. The `DELETE FROM Numbered ...` will affect the underlying table actually...

If the `NrValue` is not enough to detect a row as duplicate, just add more columns to the `PARTITION BY`

Comment: There is no table structure or data and therefore this question won't be very helpful to someone else.  But I agree with your answer +1.

Comment: Perhaps I could: `UPDATE BigTable Set Comment = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Comment )
Where NrValue IN 
(
'0001000',
'0002000',
'0003000'
)`

Comment: Or should I: `UPDATE BigTable Set Comment = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY` All columns except Comment `)
Where NrValue IN 
(
'0001000',
'0002000',
'0003000'
)`

Comment: @Kaptah As Tim Biegeleisen told you already there is not enough information for us to give a better answer. Try some research about `CTE`, `updateable CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER`...

Comment: for some reason I get `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ')'.`
It's the last parenthesis.

Comment: @Kaptah If I take my code from above and copy it into an empty query window, everything works fine...

Comment: @Kaptah Might be connected to `WITH`. This must be the first statement in the job or you must place a `;` after the line before. Some people use `;WITH` in any case...

Comment: Sorry miss-understood CTE. Was thinking it as an stored procedure and tried this without: `DELETE FROM Numbered 
WHERE DupNr>1;`   WORKS !

Answer (score 2):

You don't need update, you want to delete duplicates so why do you want that intermediate step?

Yor code should look like this:

```
    declare @t table (col1 int, col2 int);
    insert into @t values
    (1, 1), (1, 1),
    (1, 2), (1, 2),(1, 2), (1, 2),
    (3, 2), (3, 2),(3, 2);

    with cte as
    (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by 1/0) rn
    from @t
    )

    delete cte
    where rn > 1;


     select *
     from @t;
```

Sorry for not posting it in comment (rows limit and code formatting lost there)

Comment: Good example, +1 from my side, but the `1/0` looks so - uhm - forbidden... I prefer `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`

Comment: Updated question, added Table structure

Comment: it's just too long to digit, and 1/0 works :)  But if it looks bad, than order by getdate())

Comment: Just like in @Shnugo 's answer:   For some reason I get `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ')'.`
It's the last parenthesis.